Let's get critical: Feb 2015 Site Self-Evaluation
We all love Bitcoin Stack Exchange, but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.
The Site Self-Evaluation review queue is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.
Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? Post an answer below to share your thoughts and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Remember to search using incognito - otherwise you'll get biased results.

Final Results

Which bitcoin script forms should be detected when tracking wallet balance?

Net Score: 10 (Excellent: 10, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)


Is it chain of headers rather than a chain of blocks?

Net Score: 6 (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)


Is there a local wallet for Ripple?

Net Score: 4 (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)


How many transaction and btc have been cancelled?

Net Score: 4 (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)


What exactly happens when a node detects a double spend?

Net Score: 3 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 0)


What transactions will be included in the next block?

Net Score: 2 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)


Receiving `error: {"code":-25,"message":""}` on sendrawtransaction with v0.9.3

Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 3)


How to convert encrypted wallet.dat to decrypted? (Yes, I know the password)

Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)


Creating your own Bitcoin price ticker

Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 1)


why is bitcoind is missing from /usr/local/bin?

Net Score: 0 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 2)


[Satisfactory] Is it a chain of headers rather than a chain of blocks?
The page showed up fairly well on the following Google searches:

headers chain vs block chain bitcoin
headers chain
block chain headers  [Rank 6, what the heck?]

There are about a thousand pages describing how blocks are chained, so
even though I wrote the accepted answer (and I'm happy with it), I also
don't think this is "far better than other available resources." (For
all the searches above, the block chain section that I wrote for the
Bitcoin.org developer guide ranks higher.)
I also agree with Nick that ODell that the question title could
definitely be improved.
[Satisfactory] What exactly happens when a node detects a double spend?
Non-matching searches, no results in first two pages

bitcoin double spend
bitcoin core double spend
bitcoin double spend drop
bitcoin double spend confirm

Matching searches

bitcoin node double spend
bitcoin double spend keep

This
question
came up fairly often in the search results.
I think this question and answer are excellent for being specific and
clear, but it "requires oddly specific search terms to find," so I'm
grading it satisfactory.
[Needs Improvement] Is there a local wallet for Ripple?
Non-matching searches, no results in first two pages:

ripple wallet
local ripple wallet
download ripple wallet

Matching search:

local wallet for ripple

This
question
came up in every search result, although it describes something
different and may be out of date (I don't follow Ripple).
The Ripple.com downloadable client
announcement
also came up in most searches and provides, I think, the best resource.
Because the "answer is no better than what can be found elsewhere," I'm
ranking as needs improvement.  Improvements could be further describing
the security and privacy benefits of the downloadable Ripple client, or
describing why it took so long for the Ripple project to create such a client.
Also, any contraindications for using the downloadable client would be nice.
[Excellent] Which bitcoin script forms should be detected when tracking wallet balance?
Non-matching searches, no results on first two pages:

bitcoin wallet detect
bitcoin wallet output
bitcoin wallet scriptpubkey
bitcoin wallet pubkey script

Matching searches:

bitcoin wallet script [page 2]
bitcoin wallet script match [page 1, near top]

This is an important question for wallet and other program creators,
it's clearly worded, and Nick's answer is clear and concise.  I also
think it will show up in search results for the most commonly used terms
even though there are some negative results above.  It's "well-written
and has a clear, comprehensive answer that is far better than other
available resources," so I'm rating excellent.

I'll amend this post when I get to the rest (this is a lot of work!).
Edit: not going to finish.  Hopefully 4 reviews is enough.

Which bitcoin script forms should be detected when tracking wallet balance?
I might be biased, but I think this is pretty good :). The only non-SE source I can find that touches on this is http://www.wildbunny.co.uk/blog/2014/03/18/watch_only_wallet/, but that uses bitcoin RPC to identify the transaction type and extract addresses. It doesn't go into as much detail, but it would probably be more useful to the average developer.
Is there a local wallet for Ripple?
Not much to say about this. It's a clear, concise answer. The information is available elsewhere,  although it's difficult to find.
Other SE resources:

What are the ways to create an offline Ripple wallet?
(This might be a duplicate.)

Non-SE resources:

https://xrptalk.org/topic/1266-anyone-create-a-cold-wallet/
(I have no idea why there's an xrptalk when there's perfectly good ripple.org forums.)
https://xrptalk.org/topic/1855-wallet-security-tips/

Creating your own Bitcoin price ticker
An okayish question. The best non-SE resource I can find is https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=918246.0, which doesn't go into much detail.
It's tagged with development, which I think ought to be burninated at some point.
I'll call this Satisfactory.
Receiving `error: {"code":-25,"message":""}` on sendrawtransaction with v0.9.3
He asked a clear question, which is good. He figured out the answer, and posted it to his own question, which is even better!
OTOH, it seems like a very localized question, and the views and votes reflect that. E for Effort, I guess.
Is it chain of headers rather than a chain of blocks?
This question takes the form of "misunderstanding, amiright?" which is problematic because it's really hard to search for and it makes it difficult close duplicates of the question.
DAH wrote a really good answer, but it's attached to a so-so question.
I'll add the other ones as I get to them.
